# awk : avoid substitution between two symbols

Tags: awk

I have the following lines in my *awk* program :

```
str = gensub(/`([^`]*)`/, "\\\\texttt{\\1}", "g", str);
str = gensub(/\*([^\*]*)\*/, "\\\\textbf{\\1}", "g", str);
```

These lines perform non-greedy substitution for `` `...` `` and `*...*` by resp. `\texttt{...}` and `\textbf{...}`.

I am looking for a way to avoid `*...*` substitution when it's "semi-nested" or nested in `` `...` ``, e.g. `` `...*...`...* `` or `` `...*...*...` ``.

Input and expected output :

1. `` `.*` text `^.*$` `` ---> `\texttt{.*} text \texttt{^.*$}`
2. `` `*abc*` `` ---> `\texttt{*abc*}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the two patterns `A` and `B` in a single pass, then change them later. The following merges the 2 patterns into one `(A|B)` and marks it with the prefix string `XXX`. It then looks for `XXX` and the pattern `A` for the real substitution. Similarly, for `B`.
This does not handle your semi-nested `` `a*b`c* `` case.

```
awk '{ str = $0
 str = gensub(/(`[^`]*`|\*[^\*]*\*)/, "XXX\\1", "g", str);
 str = gensub(/XXX`([^`]*)`/, "\\\\texttt{\\1}", "g", str);
 str = gensub(/XXX\*([^\*]*)\*/, "\\\\textbf{\\1}", "g", str);
 print str
}' <<\!
 `abc` *abc*
 `.*` text `^.*$`
 `*abc*`
 `...*...*...`
 `...*...`...*
!
```

Output

```
 \texttt{abc} \textbf{abc}
 \texttt{.*} text \texttt{^.*$}
 \texttt{*abc*}
 \texttt{...*...*...}
 \texttt{...*...}...*
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just realize that the semi-nested case doesn't really happen. So, you solve my problems.